# Union? Intersect? Or inversed intersect?

Tags: sql, oracle, union, intersect

I'm working on a select statement that should return the class for each of the school days. There are 4 school days before the cycle starts over again. (e.g. Monday = Day1, Tuesday = Day2...Thursday = Day4, Friday = Day1..etc )

Some students may have 1 period off on certain days, in which case we should display an empty space on that day/period combination.

At the moment, the select statement only returns days which have a value.

Example:

```
            Day 1    Day 2    Day 3    Day 4
Period 1    class    class    off      class
Period 2    class    class    class    off
Period 3    off      class    class    class
Period 4    class    off      class    class
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to have the select statement return an empty row (with null values) in place of the period that is off on a certain day. I tried adding Unions with the day as the only value.

This isn't working as I'm getting my first 3 rows and then the 4 others, but what I actually want is the first 3 rows (e.g. with the days 1,3,4) and the last union'ed row (e.g. day 2) in which case I can then afterwards do an order by on the day.

How can I do this? Should I be using an intersect? ..or the opposite of an intersect?
Also this is for an Oracle database.

**Select statement:**

```
select spct.course_code||'-'||spct.course_section as course,t.school_cycle_day as jour,p.legal_first_name,p.legal_surname,sc.room_no
from   student_program_class_tracks@trl spct,class_meetings@trl cm,school_classes@trl sc,persons@trl p,timeslots@trl t,school_timeline_periods@trl tsp
where  spct.school_code=cm.school_code
and    spct.school_code=sc.school_code
and    spct.school_code=t.school_code
and    spct.school_code=tsp.school_code
and    spct.school_year=cm.school_year
and    spct.school_year=sc.school_year
and    spct.school_year=t.school_year
and    spct.school_year=tsp.school_year
and    t.school_year_track=tsp.school_year_track
and    t.school_timeline_code=tsp.school_timeline_code
and    t.school_period=tsp.school_period
and    spct.class_code=cm.class_code
and    spct.class_code=sc.class_code
and    sc.reporting_teacher=p.person_id
and    cm.block=t.block
and    spct.school_code='73'
and    spct.school_year='20122013'
and    spct.person_id='000170629'
and    cm.semester='2'
and    cm.term='1'
and    t.school_period='1'
and    ((spct.start_date <= sysdate and spct.end_date >= sysdate) or spct.demit_indicator='0')
--order by t.school_cycle_day

UNION

SELECT '','1','','','' from DUAL

UNION

SELECT '','2','','','' from DUAL

UNION

SELECT '','3','','','' from DUAL

UNION

SELECT '','4','','','' from DUAL;
```

**Output:**

```
Course         Jour    Legal_first_name   Legqal_surname     Room_no
PPL4OO-03      2       François           Belle-Isle     1-139
SBI4UU-02      4       Louise             Bérubé             1-155
TFC4EE-02      3       Gino               Proulx             1-127
           1
```

Thanks for any help you can provide!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If what you are saying is that you want 4 rows per pupil then something like the following should do it.

```
SELECT
    B.course
    A.school_cycle_day,
    B.legal_first_name,
    B.legal_surname,
    B.room_no
FROM
    (
        SELECT '1' AS school_cycle_day
        FROM DUAL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT '2'
        FROM DUAL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT '3'
        FROM DUAL

        UNION ALL

        SELECT '4'
        FROM DUAL
    ) A
    LEFT JOIN
   (
      select
           spct.course_code||'-'||spct.course_section as course,
           t.school_cycle_day as jour,
           p.legal_first_name,
           p.legal_surname,
           sc.room_no
      from
           student_program_class_tracks@trl spct,
           class_meetings@trl cm,
           school_classes@trl sc,
           persons@trl p,
           timeslots@trl t,
           school_timeline_periods@trl tsp
      where
           spct.school_code=cm.school_code and
           spct.school_code=sc.school_code and
           spct.school_code=t.school_code and
           spct.school_code=tsp.school_code and
           spct.school_year=cm.school_year and
           spct.school_year=sc.school_year and
           spct.school_year=t.school_year and
           spct.school_year=tsp.school_year and
           t.school_year_track=tsp.school_year_track and
           t.school_timeline_code=tsp.school_timeline_code and
           t.school_period=tsp.school_period and
           spct.class_code=cm.class_code and
           spct.class_code=sc.class_code and
           sc.reporting_teacher=p.person_id and
           cm.block=t.block and
           spct.school_code='73' and
           spct.school_year='20122013' and
           spct.person_id='000170629' and
           cm.semester='2' and
           cm.term='1' and
           t.school_period='1' and
           ((spct.start_date <= sysdate and spct.end_date >= sysdate) or  spct.demit_indicator='0')
) B ON A.school_cycle_day = B.school_cycle_day
```